Why does Rust users crate return "root" in list of groups for user?
I'm using the User::groups() function in the Rust users crate, which calls C function getgrouplist() to get Linux groups containing the effective user:
fn main() {
    let uid = users::get_effective_uid();
    if let Some(user) = users::get_user_by_uid(uid) {
        println!("Running as {:?}", &user);
        if let Some(groups) = user.groups() {
            for group in groups {
                println!("Member of {:?}", group);
            }
        }
    }
}

This outputs the following:
Running as User(1000, hwalters)
Member of Group(1000, hwalters)
Member of Group(4, adm)
Member of Group(24, cdrom)
Member of Group(27, sudo)
Member of Group(30, dip)
Member of Group(46, plugdev)
Member of Group(122, lpadmin)
Member of Group(135, lxd)
Member of Group(136, sambashare)
Member of Group(0, root)

However, the Linux groups command outputs the following:
$ groups hwalters
hwalters : hwalters adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare

I am curious why the Rust code includes group "root" where the command does not.  I can explicitly remove UID 0, but I would prefer not to, as there may be scenarios where that would not make sense.  Can anyone tell me what's going on here?
UPDATE: For anyone coming across this in future, you can use crate uzers instead of users.  This fixes the bug described in Usamoi's reply.

I believe it's just a bug. This crate calls getgrouplist (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getgrouplist.3.html) to get the list of all groups for a user.
pub fn get_user_groups<S: AsRef<OsStr> + ?Sized>(username: &S, gid: gid_t) -> Option<Vec<Group>> {
    // MacOS uses i32 instead of gid_t in getgrouplist for unknown reasons
    #[cfg(all(unix, target_os="macos"))]
    let mut buff: Vec<i32> = vec![0; 1024];
    #[cfg(all(unix, not(target_os="macos")))]
    let mut buff: Vec<gid_t> = vec![0; 1024];

    let name = CString::new(username.as_ref().as_bytes()).unwrap();
    let mut count = buff.len() as c_int;

    #[cfg(feature = "logging")]
    trace!("Running getgrouplist for user {:?} and group #{}", username.as_ref(), gid);

    // MacOS uses i32 instead of gid_t in getgrouplist for unknown reasons
    #[cfg(all(unix, target_os="macos"))]
    let res = unsafe {
        libc::getgrouplist(name.as_ptr(), gid as i32, buff.as_mut_ptr(), &mut count)
    };

    #[cfg(all(unix, not(target_os="macos")))]
    let res = unsafe {
        libc::getgrouplist(name.as_ptr(), gid, buff.as_mut_ptr(), &mut count)
    };

    if res < 0 {
        None
    }
    else {
        buff.dedup();
        buff.into_iter()
            .filter_map(|i| get_group_by_gid(i as gid_t))
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
            .into()
    }
}

It should truncate buff to count, but it doesn't.
This crate is unmaintained for 4 years and if you run cargo-audit on a package that depends on users, you'll get RUSTSEC-2023-0040. So I suggest you find another crate to replace this crate.

Turns out that library has been adopted as crate "uzers", and the bug you spotted has been fixed already. Thanks again!
